# How do you use swagger-js with a service that requires manual download of its spec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to use [`swagger-js`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) to generate client code for a service that requires manual download of its spec. That is, the service publishes its spec, but its not downloadable in an automated way.

I've got the spec on the filesystem, but the problem is that [`swagger-js`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js), which depends on [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch), which in turn depends on [`node-fetch`](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch), doesn't support `file://` urls or absolute filesystem paths.

Relevant issues are https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1044, https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/76 & https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/75.

Is there a workaround for this scenario until these issues are resolved?

Comment: Bit inconvenient, but you could host the file on a local server running on your machine? Something like [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) or a bog-standard Express app might do the trick. Obviously that's not a great solution though.

Comment: Yeah, thought of that, but abandonded due to too much work/infra smell.  Thanks, though.